# Angular ng-style background image when url contain spaces

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to apply a background image to a div by using the angular `ng-style` and it works fine as long as the URL does not contain spaces.

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + parentIMGLink + ')'}"
```

When there is space in URL like `parentIMGLink = servername.images/there is name.png` it does not work. On the other hand:

```
img ng-src={{parentIMGLink }}
```

Works fine. For sure I can manage so that names on the server wont contain spaces but is there any possibility to make ng-style work?

Comment: what do you mean by `does not work` ?

Comment: @Hacketo Probably that it won't find the image...

Answer (score 7):

Just like in css you have to wrap your the image url in quotes:

```
.rule{ background-image: url('/some/image url.png') }
```

You have to do the same here:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(\'{{imageUrl}}\')'}">
```

Comment: Man, this does not work for me .... Syntax is correct, but once i inspect element, the background style attribute is empty

Comment: @ThembelaniM, have you tried using `bypassSecurityTrustStyle`? See this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419662/why-sanitizer-bypasssecuritytruststyle-returns-warning-when-setting-style-backg/49437507#49437507

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. In JS, replace " " with %20 (Percent-encoded space).

```
parentIMGLink = parentIMGLink.replace(" ", "%20");
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. Did not think about that it might be solved by encoding the character. But had to use `parentIMGLink = parentIMGLink.replace(/ /g, "%20");` because of multiple spaces

Comment: @sniegoman Glad to hear that. Filenames always mess up when you don't percent-encode special characters. So keep that in mind until next time!