# Angularjs ng-style background image doesn't work when the URL contains brackets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-style, angularjs-ng-style

I'm using the **ngStyle** directive in AngularJs to change the Background Image of an element and I've noticed that **the style is not applied when the URL of the image contains brackets "()".**

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(https://sumosoft.blob.core.windows.net/rescorp/properties/NW1/Marylebone%20Road/Harley%20House/63/27283_hi_res_1_(1)_1200.jpg)' }">
    Hello
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19425/)

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19426/ `'` was the issue!

Comment: Omg you're my hero, I wish I could upvote this. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33423861/406804