# Why sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle returns warning when setting [style.background-image] attribute?

Tags: angular, sanitization

I have a simple piece of code that won't work:

```
<div class="cover"
    [style.background-image]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(/assets/img/picture (1).jpg)')">
</div>
```

The `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle` returns the following message:

```
SafeValue must use [property]=binding: url(/assets/img/picture (1).jpg) (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

Also tried to move sanitization to a custom pipe, the result is the same.

When trying the following solutions Angular ignores `style.background-image` completely:

1. `[style.background-image]="'url(' + photo + ')'"`
2. `[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + photo + ')'}"`

Why?

*Angular: 5.2.4*

Comment: Well, I managed to fix the problem by removing the space in picture name (picture (1).jpg >> picture(1).jpg). Still curious why spaces in image url break ng binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem occurs when you have an image url with *spaces* in it and the string, which is passed to css url() is *without quotes*:

```
[style.background-image]="'url(' + photo + ')'"
```

The code above works fine when your url has no spaces. If there are spaces just wrap actual image url with *single quotes*:

```
[style.background-image]="'url(\'' + photo + '\')'"
```

**By the way**, if this still does not work, try [disabling Angular's built-in sanitization](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) for the value passed in:

```
bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style)
```

You can create a pipe for that:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  transform(style) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
  }
}
```